# Applying Korean Tourist visa from Nagpur or Bengaluru

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea, vfs-global, bangalore

I will be travelling to South Korea on 31th MAY, 2023 for tourism purposes. Before travelling, I have to get my visa approved. So, I was looking for some service based out of Nagpur/Bengaluru which can assist me in the same. Usually, I apply through VFS global. However this time, the service is only available for Delhi & Kolkata as mentioned on their website https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/kor/attend-centre as well as here https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/in-en/wpge/m_2660/contents.do . I was wondering if anybody else  is facing the same problem and/or have a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The embassy of the Republic of Korea in New Delhi, [states](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/in-chennai-en/brd/m_2785/view.do?seq=750144&page=1) :

> Jurisdiction for Visa Submission
>
> ☞ To Embassy of the Republic of Korea in New Delhi
>
> Arunachal Pradesh, Assam, Bihar, Chhattisgarh, Haryana, Himachal
> Pradesh, Jharkhand, Manipur, Meghalaya, Mizoram, Nagaland, Odisha,
> Punjab, Rajasthan, Sikkim, Tripura, Uttar Pradesh, Uttarakhand, West
> Bengal, Union Territory (Delhi, Chandigarh, J&K, Ladakh)
>
> ☞ To Consulate General of the Republic of Korea in Mumbai
>
> Maharashtra, Gujarat, Goa, Madhya Pradesh, Telangana, Union Territory
> (Daman & Diu, Dadra & Nagar Haveli)
>
> ☞ To Consulate General of the Republic of Korea in Chennai
>
> Andra Pradesh, Kerala, Karnataka, Tamil Nadu, Union Territory
> (Lakshadweep, Puducherry)

They talk about the state you actually live in

---

If you live in any of the states under the Chennai consulate jurisdiction, the [rules](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/in-chennai-en/brd/m_2785/view.do?seq=750144&page=1) are as follows :

> 1. Visa applicants to collect tokens from ground floor of the consulate building at 9AM. 17 tokens for individuals and 8 tokens for
>    agents are issued on a first come first serve basis only at sharp 9AM.
>    NO EXCEPTIONS OR PRIOR APPOINTMENTS
> 2. Visa applicants without check list or documents mentioned on the checklist will not be allowed to submit their application
> 3. Those creating any issues/disturbance during token distribution or those submitting fake documents during application will be de barred
>    from further submissions
> 4. Please avoid calling for visa status enquiry. Visa status will be uploaded after 15 days from submission
> 5. Visa once approved can be collected from consulate between 3 to 4PM.

The first point means that only 17 individual applications will be allowed to be lodged on that day

---

If you live in any of the states under the Mumbai consulate jurisdiction, the applications are to be lodged at select travel agencies [link to the relevant information](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/in-mumbai-en/brd/m_1978/view.do?seq=717617&page=1)

---

If you live in any of the other states, you indeed need to visit the VFSGlobal offices in New Delhi and Kolkata